# overflow isn’t working in MEAN.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mean-stack, meanjs

The `overflow` isn’t working in MEAN.JS app. Any idea how to do it?

The scroll works no matter we keep `overflow` as `hidden`.

```html
<section>
  <div 
       class="cbp-spmenu-push"
       style="overflow:hidden"
       ng-class="{
           'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' : leftOpen,
           'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' : rightOpen,
           'ovh' : leftOpen,
           'ovh' : rightOpen
       }"
       ng-controller="HomeController"
  >
    <!-- CONTENT-->
  </div>    
</section>
```

Comment: The scrollbar is probably attached to another element

Comment: Writing a whole sentence in uppercase does not improve readability.